# Instead of Update Trigger on bit column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a small table (code below) with PageKey (int), SendNotification (bit) with 5 possible PageKeys at the moment.

The requirement is to not have more than 1 flag (`SendNotification`) active at the same time, so I want to create a trigger that would not allow changing the flag to True when there is already another pageKey with active flag.

I wrote the following trigger but it doesn't seem to work. Also, if you have any other (better) solutions to accomplish this in SQL Server 2012, I'd appreciate it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Notification_Flag 
ON dbo.t_Notification_Flag
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @countOfExistingFlags INT;
    DECLARE @PageKey INT;

    SELECT @countOfExistingFlags = COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.t_Notification_Flag
    WHERE SendNotification = 1;

    SELECT @PageKey = inserted.PageKey
    FROM inserted;

    IF @countOfExistingFlags > 1
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'There is an existing active flag. No changes has been done.'; 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.t_Notification_Flag
        SET SendNotification = 1
        WHERE PageKey = @PageKey;
    END;
END;
GO
```

Table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t_Notification_Flag]
(
    [PageKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SendNotification] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [NotificationMessage] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [NotificationHeader] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Country_Key] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Your trigger has a major flaw. It assumes there is only 1 value in inserted. Triggers fire once per operation. Also, you should be careful of issuing a rollback inside your trigger. This can wreak havoc on an application that has a transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your goal without trigger - but just with filtered unique index.

Something like:

```
create table dbo.#Temp (PageKey int, Send_Notification bit)
create unique index IX_Temp on dbo.#temp(Send_Notification) where Send_Notification = 1
```

This will not allow your table to have more than one record having `Send_Notification = 1`, so if you need to set `Send_Notification` flag for some record - you'll have to clear it first for the record currently having this flag set.

Comment: What version of SQL Server did filtered indexes become available in?

Comment: @TabAlleman as far as I remember, they are available at least in 2008 version

Comment: @AndyKorneyev thanks a lot, this solution is a lot more elegant and works the purpose perfectly. No need to reinvent the wheel ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a trigger at all for this.  Instead I would use a CHECK CONSTRAINT that checks a UDF that returns true if there are no other active flags, and false if there are.